# Null reference is returned when executing getChild() using JDOM

Tags: jdom

I have next sample of XML document and I need to detach all "link" Elements from document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://my.netscape.com/rdf/simple/0.9/" xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0">
<channel>
  <title>Slashdot</title> 
  <link>http://slashdot.org/</link> 
  <description>News for nerds, stuff that matters</description> 
  </channel>
<image>
  <title>Slashdot</title> 
  <url>http://a.fsdn.com/sd/topics/topicslashdot.gif</url> 
  <link>http://slashdot.org/</link> 
  </image>
  <atom10:link xmlns:atom10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="self" type="application/xml" href="http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot/to" /> 
  </rdf:RDF>
```

That's a code I am using

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Object next = iterator.next();
    Element element = (Element) next; 
    Namespace namespace = element.getNamespace();
    Element link = element.getChild("link",namespace);
    link.detach();
}
```

It's work well on "link" Elements without attributes

```
<link>http://slashdot.org/</link>
<link>http://slashdot.org/</link>
```

But when I want to get a next child which is also a link , but with attributes and different namespace, null object reference is returned

```
<atom10:link xmlns:atom10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="self" type="application/xml" href="http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot/to" />
```

Please help

Thanks a lot
David

Comment: I don't know well jDom, but you iterate on what kind of data? If that's the children of the rdf:RDF root, atom10:link is part of these elements, so it cannot be found as a child of these.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all elements with local name 'link', regardless of the namespace, the easiest solution is XPath. The expression `//*[local-name() = 'link]` will select all element nodes in the document whose local name is 'link'.

```
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.build(...));
    List<Element> result = XPath.selectNodes(doc, "//*[local-name() = 'link']");
    for (Element e : result)
        e.detach();
```